# How to write a windows application that can easily work with multiple third party com object?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an windows application that is tightly coupled with a third party COM Object. And through the instance of this com object, all i am doing is create, delete, save and export. Now as new requirement arised, I have to add another similar third party component but from different vendor.

I dont want to write separate application that is similar to the first one except third party dependency changed.

How should i change my windows application so that

1. I can easily switch these third party dependencies. (like loosely coupled kind of thing).
2. I dont need to maintenance separate code.

I need some directions.

Comment: Program to an interface.  The interface contains all the common methods you need to perform and you just provide an implementation utilizing each COM object.  Keyword, "abstraction".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (which may not be suitable for you) is to write an interface that all plugins will inherit, which contains the abstracted-out methods of what you need to achieve from each COM .dll. Then, each plugin is a C# Class Library which implements the interface, and passes off all of the calls to a Backend COM object.

This means that you would ship 3 new DLLs, the one that contains your interface (and is referenced by the main application and the .NET Class Library), the .NET Class Library as the main 'Plugin', and then the backend COM .dll also.

Like I say it's just one way to do it, but would get you up and running pretty quick with little overhead IMO.

---

Simplistic example:

**IPlugin.cs** [IPlugin.dll]

```
interface IPlugin
{
    bool MethodReturningTrue();
}
```

**YourPlugin.cs** [YourPlugin.dll, references IPlugin.dll]

```
class YourPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public bool MethodReturningTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**PluginHost.cs** [yourapp.exe, references IPlugin.dll]

```
class PluginHost
{
    public static IPlugin GetPlugin()
    {
        Assembly asmbly = Assembly.LoadFrom("YourPlugin.dll");
        Type objectType = asmbly.GetType("YourPlugin");
        return (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    }
}
```

**PluginUser.cs** [yourapp.exe, references IPlugin.dll]

```
class PluginUser
{
    public bool GetTrueValueFromPlugin()
    {
        IPlugin pluginObj = PluginHost.GetPlugin();
        pluginObj.MethodReturningTrue();
    }
}
```

Of course, that relies on the class being called "YourPlugin" within the "YourPlugin.dll". In a production environment to support multiple .dlls you would enumerate the .dlls, load each assembly, and use Reflection to find classes within that Assembly which implement the `IPlugin` interface. If you need two way communications between the plugin and the host, you can make another interface (ie. `IPluginHost`) and add a method to `IPlugin` which accepts an instance of `IPluginHost`. The implementing classes can then store that instance and call methods to have the two way comms in place.

Comment: Can you lead me to any suitable example in c#?

Comment: Rudi. Does Dependency Injection fit in this requirement? Just curious, even DI is a learning curve for me.

Comment: @user1327064 Well, yes in a way, since your definition of the requirements (Interface) is separate from your implementation. In honesty I've never seen the need for a fancy IoC framework to achieve loosely-coupled extensibility.

Comment: Rudi. Class '**YourPlugin**' has an event '**_obj.OnNewEntry**' that is raised by third party dll (referenced in YourPlugin class). How will I raise this event in class '**PluginUser**'

Comment: @user1327064 You can define an event on an interface (ie. `IPlugin`) and as such will be able to subscribe to it just like you would any normal event.